# Try Catch not as intended

Tags: powershell, try-catch

So I have this script working except I cannot get the computer name to display when there is an error, I understand that is because the computer is offline and the first Get computername cmd is an error as well, but I have tried multiple ways to perform this function with one thing or another not working.

```
gc "\\server\s$\powershellscripts\LabMachines\*.txt" | ForEach-Object{
    Try{   
        $wdt = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_ -Ea Stop
        $cdt = Get-Content "\\$_\C$\file\*.txt" -Ea Stop
    }
    Catch{
        $wdt= $_
        $cdt = 'Offline or NoFile'
    }
    $wdt | Select @{n='WorkStation';e={$_.PSComputerName}},@{n='Version';e={$cdt}}
} | ogv -Title 'Versions'
$host.enternestedprompt()
```

In a different attempt I have used this script, but this one below formats the information in rows instead of column like the first one.

```
Get-Content "\\server\s$\powershellscripts\LabMachines\*.txt" | ForEach-Object  {   
    Try{ 
        @{ComputerName=$_}
        @{Version = Get-Content "\\$_\C$\file\*.txt" -Ea Stop}
    }
    Catch{
        @{Version = 'Offline or NoFile' }
    }
} #| out-file \\localhost\c$\users\public\Desktop\version.csv
```

Any attempt to take my script and merge it with one someone suggested to me "the second one" breaks it completely. To reiterate the top script give me the format output in columns I want but the bottom script gives the catch error "ComputerName Error" I need but has the output in harder to read row outfile.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using (check `$PSVersionTable`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `catch` block, `$_` no longer refers to the pipeline item, but to the error that was caught.

Assign `$_` to a different variable and you can reuse it inside the `catch` block:

```
Get-Content "\\server\s$\powershellscripts\LabMachines\*.txt" | ForEach-Object{
    Try{   
        $ComputerName = $_
        $wdt = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName -Ea Stop
        $cdt = Get-Content "\\$_\C$\file\*.txt" -Ea Stop
    }
    Catch{
        $wdt = @{PSComputerName = $ComputerName}
        $cdt = 'Offline or NoFile'
    }
    $wdt | Select @{n='WorkStation';e={$_.PSComputerName}},@{n='Version';e={$cdt}}
}
```

Pipe to `Export-Csv` at the end if you want to output it to a CSV file:

```
} |Export-Csv C:\users\public\Desktop\version.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: It was a missing curly bracket at first but now it works like a charm. So especially after this I am learning that separating the logic in these powershell scripts really helps a lot, in one way more variables assigned the more you can achieve. Thanks so much. **One more question on this script- for the files that have no content to create an additional error all I need to do is add another catch for $null info?**

Comment: You could do `@{n='Version';e={if($cdt){$cdt}else{"File was empty"}}}`

Comment: You are a beast. I understood everything you taught me and I very much appreciate it. Could you tell me how that if statement works. I see it working but I can't say for sure how. I am guessing that the ($cdt) means that if the variable has a value then {$cdt} but if not then echo File was empty.

Comment: If $cdt is either $null (no value) or an empty string, or 0, it will evaluate to $false, and "File was empty" will be the result. Otherwise the value of $cdt will be the result, yes :-)

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, please consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left

Comment: I did mark it as answered but my score is under 15 so it won't publicly post. But you helped me learn a ton. And thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I so I wanted to throw my finished product with a few additional things I learned. Here it is.

```
Function Version {
$i=1
$LabMachines = "\\server\s$\powershellscripts\LabMachines\*.txt" 
$Total = 107 #a manual number for now

Get-Content $LabMachines | ForEach-Object{
   Try{ 
      $ComputerName=$_
      $wdt = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName -Ea Stop 
      $cdt = Get-Content "\\$_\C$\file\*.txt" -Ea Stop 
      }
     Catch{
          $wdt = @{PSComputerName = $ComputerName}
          $cdt = 'Offline'
          }
 $wdt | Select @{n='WorkStation';e={$_.PSComputerName}},@{n='Version';e={if($cdt){$cdt}else{"Error with Version.txt"}}} 
                $i++ 
                $percent = [Math]::Round($i / $Total*100) } | Tee-Object -file \\localhost\c$\users\public\desktop\versions.csv | 
                 Select @{n='%Complete';e={if(!($null)){$percent}else{"NULL"}}},
                 @{n='Number';e={if(!($null)){$i}else{"NULL"}}},
                 @{n='Computer';e={if(!($null)){$ComputerName}else{"NULL"}}},
                 @{n='Version';e={if($cdt){$cdt}else{"Error with Version.txt"}}} }
```

The changes I made in addition to the answer above was it will show progress in the console as a percent, number, computername, version txt as it completes. Also I made this into a function so we can run it  and get the .csv file on our own desktop. To be fancier you could put in a line to do a line count to achieve the manual number I am using.

Thanks so much for the help I learned alot.